# Cannot write the message to the server more than two times by asio

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-asio

After some survey on [this page](http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/asio.html), I try to write a small program to write the message to a local server developed by python script.So far so good, the problem is I can only write the message to the server one time only.

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string input;
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(io_service);
boost::array<char, 4096> buffer;

void connect_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec)
{
    if(!ec){
        boost::asio::write(sock, boost::asio::buffer(input));
    }
}

void resolve_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator it)
{
    if (!ec){
        sock.async_connect(*it, connect_handler);
    }
}

void write_to_server(std::string const &message)
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("127.0.0.1", "9999");
    input = message;
    resolver.async_resolve(query, resolve_handler);
    io_service.run();
}

int main()
{
    write_to_server("123");
    write_to_server("456");
}
```

Here are the python script

```
import SocketServer

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
    The RequestHandler class for our server.

    It is instantiated once per connection to the server, and must
    override the handle() method to implement communication to the
    client.
    """

    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
        print self.data
        # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
        self.request.sendall(self.data.upper())     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999

    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)

    # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
    # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: You are writing in `connect_handler`. You connect to server only once. You probabably need to close connection at the end of `write_to_server`, just make sure it is open first! All in all, C++ piece of code looks plain wrong to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `io_service` was not `reset` between the two uses.

You'll have to call the `reset` member function if you want to use the same `io_service` again after it was stopped.

```
write_to_server("123");
io_service.reset();
write_to_server("456");
```

---

That said, this is not the best way to design this whole stuff, you should probably use the same `io_service` and never stop it, but since the `run` member function of `io_service` will be the main loop of your program, you'll have to either send your messages one right after the other in your connection callbacks, or create some kind of event driven program where you send a message based on user input (e.g read on stdin or an socket etc.). But this should only be considered if you're developing a bigger more complex program.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I am a newbie of network(and asio), by now I only try to design a simple program to send some data to the server, will consider your advices when I know more details about network and asio

Comment: You're welcome. I highly suggest watching this : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-lTwGJRx0o

Comment: Also see the edit, i've narrowed down the problem for this case.